# HTML5.qrCode| InstaScan | TypeError: Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': Overload resolution failed

Tags: javascript, html, qr-code, html5-qrcode

I was trying to implement Instascan from "https://rawgit.com/schmich/instascan-builds/master/instascan.min.js.". If we use the online file then the scanner is working fine but when I try to copy the file and use it from my local system it shows the below error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDqyo.png)

Html file code for creating instascan instance:

```
let scanner = new Instascan.Scanner({
   video: document.getElementById('scanner')
});
   scanner.addListener('scan', function(content, image) {
   console.log(content);
});
```

JS file code where error is showing:

`case 3: return this._stream = i.sent, i.abrupt("return", window.URL.createObjectURL(this._stream)); case 5: case "end":`

I have tried to avoid the URL.createObjectUrl but nothing worked. Can anyone help me with this.